# Cronjob: Python script not writing to file

Tags: python, cron, raspbian

I'm working on raspbian and wrote a python script which communicates via RS232 with some hardware relatet to pysical IO States of the Raspberry. It also writes to a logfile.

Everything works fine when I start the script from command line:
`pi@raspberrypi ~/scripts $ python steppercontrol.py`

I added the scrip as a cronjob ( `sudo crontab -e` )

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/scripts/steppercontrol.py
```

The script works and is running after reboot, but the logfile is not written
syslog gives the following

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep CRON
May 29 12:05:16 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2106]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
May 29 12:17:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2456]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 29 13:17:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2509]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

The chmods should be ok:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/scripts $ ls -lh
total 16K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 3.1K May 27 12:55 steppercontrol.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi  249 May 29 12:05 stepperlog
```

IMO it's not related to python itself. I also could not manage to redirect stdout from the script (as cronjob) to a file. I am lost, here is my script:

Btw: it's my first python script and generally i am not very good with linux, but raspbian and google make things easy ;-)

```
import serial
import time
import pifacedigitalio as p
import datetime

# function to read data by busy waiting
# timeout is enable, non blocking
def getData( p ):
   "get data busy waiting"

   d = ''
   if p.inWaiting() <= 0:
     return d

   time.sleep(0.3)
   while p.inWaiting() > 0:
      d += p.read(1)
   return d
# end of function

# main program logig
# init serial communication
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, baudrate=9600, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO, timeout=1.0)
p.init()
for i in range(0,8):
   p.digital_write(i,0)
   p.digital_write_pullup(i, 1)

logfile = open('/home/pi/scripts/stepperlog','a')
i = datetime.datetime.now()
logfile.write(str(i) + " script started \n")
print(str(i) + " script started \n")

# query hello world string and write answer to screen
port.write("?ver\r")
d = getData(port)
print(">> " + d + "\n")
port.write("!a\r")

# setup stepper drive
port.write("!axis 1 0 0\r")            # disable all axis excep X-axis
port.write("!pitch 1 1 1\r")           # set pitch of rod ... needed?
port.write("!cur 1 1 1\r")             # set current per motor to 1 A
port.write("!accel 0.5 0.5 0.5\r")     # set accelleration to value in m/s^2
port.write("!velfac 0.1 0.1 0.1\r")    # reduce speed by facor 1/10

pinList = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
prevSelection = -2

while 1:
   for i in range(0,6):
      pinList[i] = p.digital_read(i)
      p.digital_write(i,pinList[i])
      #print(">> I/O " + str(i) + " : " + str(pinList[i]))

   speed = 0;
   curSelection = -1

   if pinList[0] == 1:      # position 1
      speed = 5;            # move down fast 5mm/s
      curSelection = 0
   elif pinList[1] == 1:    # position 3
      speed = -0.1;         # move up 50 um/s
      curSelection = 1
   elif pinList[2] == 1:    # position 5
      speed = -0.2;         # move up 100 um/s
      curSelection = 2
   elif pinList[3] == 1:    # position 7
      speed = -0.3;         # move up 100 um/s
      curSelection = 3
   elif pinList[4] == 1:    # position 9
      speed = -0.4;         # move up 100 um/s
      curSelection = 4
   elif pinList[5] == 1:    # position 11
      speed = -5;           # move up fast 5 mm/s
      curSelection = 5

   calcspeed = float(speed)
   calcspeed *= 10/1.36                # factor 10/100 corresponds to speed reduction from above !

   if curSelection != prevSelection:
      i = datetime.datetime.now()
      logfile.write(str(i) + " " + str(prevSelection) + " " + str(curSelection) + " " + str(speed) + " " + str(calcspeed) + "\n")
      print(str(i) + " " + str(prevSelection) + " " + str(curSelection) + " " + str(speed) + " " + str(calcspeed))
   prevSelection = curSelection

   speed = "%.10f" % calcspeed         # float to string
   port.write("!speed" + speed + "\r")

   wait = 0.1
   time.sleep(float(wait))
```

Comment: cron doesn't run your profile and .bashrc, so proper environment variables are not always set. If I had to guess, I would think that you are missing your `PYTHONPATH`. You can `echo $PYTHONPATH` from a terminal to see what it should be to run the script correctly, and then add a line `PYTHONPATH=...` in your crontab to set it.

Comment: Checked that, ... PYTHONPATH did confuse me since it's emtpty in my terminal (bash) from wich the script runs fine `pi@raspberrypi ~ $ echo $PYTHONPATH ` .... edit no newline visible here ... output of echo is nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the answer is obvious!
I did not flush the output. For stdout, stderr:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stderr.flush()
```

for opened file:

```
logfile.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cron job is writing something to stdout or stderr - cron collects that and tries to mail it to you, but your system has no MTA installed (hence the log message "No MTA installed").  Try redirecting stderr and stdout to a file, and you will probably get more information as to what the problem is.

Alternately, you could install an MTA and let it send you the output - this will help you with any other problems you encounter with cron tasks in the future:

> sudo apt-get install postfix

Comment: wtf is wrong with this editorwindow... how do I add line breaks ? I am sorry for the formatting, here's my text: ....................... I tried redirecting the output (stderr and stdout)... ``@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/scripts/steppercontrol.py >> /home/pi/scripts/log.txt 2>&1
#*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/scripts/testlog.py >> /home/pi/scripts/log.txt 2>&1`` .............. first line does not work, second one does

Comment: isntalling postfix does not change anything. Did not expect it to do, but tried. ...... There's something weird. Second script above is executed every minute, doing the exact same thing (writing to file and stdout, both is logged and received). Only difference is the timing statement (@reboot and every minute)